# Shell POSIX two nested while read and read from stdin not working

Tags: shell

I have that sample script:

```
#!/bin/sh
while read ll </dev/fd/4; do
     echo "1 "$ll

     while read line; do
          echo $line
          read   input </dev/fd/3
          echo "$input"
     done 3<&0 <notify-finished

done 4<output_file
```

Currently The first loop do not iterate just stays on line 1. How do I fix that without bashisms because it has to be highly portable. Thanks.

Comment: `/dev/fd` is either a Linuxism or a bashism (bash emulates it on non-Linux operating systems, but not all shells do), so you're *already* nonportable. Use `<&4`, not `</dev/fd/4`.

Comment: Please extend your code to be a MCVE -- creating `output_file` and `notify-finished`, so it will run in a way that successfully demonstrates your bug without the person who wants to see your problem needing to do anything else.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It turned out it was the `</dev/fd/4` notation that was causing the trouble. If you second that comment as an answer, I'll accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code **already has** bashisms. Here, I'm taking them out (and simplifying the FD handling for better readability):

```
#!/bin/sh
while read ll <&4; do            # read from output_file
     printf '%s\n' "1 $ll"

     while read line <&3; do     # read from notify-finished
          printf '%s\n' "$line"
          read input             # read from stdin
          printf '%s\n' "$input"
     done 3<notify-finished

done 4<output_file
```

Run the script as follows:

```
echo "output_file" >output_file
echo "notify-finished" >notify-finished
echo "stdout" | ./yourscript
```

...and it correctly exits with the following output:

```
1 output_file
notify-finished
stdout
```

---

Notes:

- `echo`'s behavior is wildly nonportable across POSIX platforms. See the APPLICATION USAGE section of [the POSIX spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html), which advises using `printf` instead.
- `/dev/fd/##` is not specified by POSIX; it is an extension made available both by Linux distributions (creating a symlink to `/proc/self/fd` -- `/proc` being itself an unspecified extension) and by bash itself. Use `<&4` in place of `</dev/fd/4`.
- You *probably* want to use the `-r` argument to `read` -- which is POSIX-specified, and prevents the default behavior of treating backslashes as escape sequences for newlines and characters in IFS. Without it, `foo\bar` is read as `foobar`, thus not reading your data as it truly exists in its input sources.